# Google Hangouts plugin is not working as I want in Chromium

Tags: chromium, google-hangouts

Am I the only one experiencing problems with the Google Hangouts plugin? I did some changes so that I see the Hangouts icon in the topbar. But it happens once and a while that I cant open the window. The only thing I can do in that case is close Chromium and reopen it again. I have Hangouts with multiple people in the same chat. So Pidgin or Empathy is not something what I can count as workaround.

Also when I closed the browser and want to reopen it I get the Contact List of Hangouts and not the Browser itself. I have to open it by using right-click on the Chromium shortcut.

Comment: Not just that. It crashes all the time on Chromium. It works as intended on Google Chrome. Maybe we should file a bug to Chromium?

Comment: Are they different versions of Chromium/Google Chrome? If not, I suspect something else.